# NSControl subclass can't read the target?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

The following code:

```
- (void) setTarget:(id)anObject {   
    NSLog(@"anObject: %@",anObject);
    [super setTarget:anObject];
    NSLog(@"Target: %@",[self target]);
}
```

has this output:

```
anObject: <DropZoneViewController: 0x15dd5770>
Target: (null)
```

This is in a subclass of NSControl. So what am I doing wrong?

What I'm trying to achieve: I have an NScontrol that accepts dragging objects. When the dragging ends, I'd like to send the control's action to its target. But how do I get the control's action & target if this above doesn't work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NSControl` doesn’t store it’s own target, that is what it’s cell is supposed to do.

So there are two reasons this might fail:

1. **Your control doesn’t have a cell**
   In this case you really should create a subclass of `NSActionCell` to implement your control. Your subclass of `NSControl` shouldn’t do much besides setting up the cell.
   If you don’t want to do it the right way by using a `NSCell` you’ll have to add instance variables to your `NSControl` subclass to store the target and action and override the getters and setters to use them.
2. **Your cell is not a subclass of `NSActionCell`.** A regular `NSCell` doesn’t store a target either.
   If you’re using a custom cell that is not a subclass of `NSActionCell` just change it so that it does inherit from `NSActionCell` instead of `NSCell`. If you cannot do this (for example because you’re subclassing a `NSCell` subclass you cannot change) you’ll have to add the instance variables for target and selector to your cell class and override it’s setters and getters.